# dojotoolkit: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file

Tags: javascript, dojo, filesystems, xmlhttprequest

i am encountering a problem while developing a piece of software with the dojotoolkit (The version i have to use is 1.8.1 revision 29801).
Here a little bit background. The Software is a C#.Net application in which a webbrowser control displays some webpages which are located on a users filesystem respectively a file server. 
I debugged the software until now with netbeans which simulates a webserver.
Now i tried to open it just with my Application which ended up with the very unpleasing result that it didn't worked. I tried to open it with Chrome and the Internet explorer and received the same result.
i delimited the problem to one line.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dojotoolkit20/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true, useXDomain: true"></script>
```

i thought the useXDomain would be sufficient but it seems that i am mistaken in this regard.

in the whole my html file looks now like this:

```
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <title>DojoTest</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dojotoolkit20/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true, useXDomain: true"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The internet explorer shows me that the error is in the dojo.js

```
    req.getText = function(url, async, onLoad){
        var xhr = getXhr();
        xhr.open('GET', fixupUrl(url), false); //Here it says Access denied(url: "dojotoolkit20/dojo/parser.js")
```

Google Chrome reports:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///E:/HTML/public_html/dojotoolkit20/dojo/parser.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. /E:/HTML/public_html/index.html:1
Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///E:/HTML/public_html/dojotoolkit20/dojo/parser.js'.
```

Is there any way how i can accomplish the loading of the file ? installing a webserver is not an option for my users ;)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace XMLHttpRequest with something written in C# and exposed to your web view.

Comment: As you can see the only thing I am doing in this above example is setting the script tag with the dojo.js all other things come from dojo.js. What i mean is: It should work in IE.

Comment: Why should it work in IE? You're using third party JavaScript designed for use on HTTP websites and trying to use it on a file system instead of HTTP.

Comment: Parts of the software are already made by other developers with dojotoolkit, this works all fine and dandy. I can't find why it works in their code and not in mine. It should work properly in IE because the basis for the webbrowser control in C# is an Internet Explorer

Comment: That error is a security implementation of the browser..  This is done so that malicious website cannot just grab data from a users harddrive.  For chrome you have to start it with a flag to allow it to read from the file system.  IE probably has something to the same effect.

Comment: I think it would also be possible to edit my c# webbrowser control so that it uses this flag, but i am not quite sure how this goes. A quick search returned nothing very helpful. But i'll try to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really explain why it works but here is a solution for this problem.

altering this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dojotoolkit20/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true, useXDomain: true"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dojotoolkit20/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true, async:true, useXDomain: true"></script>
```

The async:true seems to solve the problem.

Now I don't get the error message and it opens up nicely. I still have some problems with the dojo datagrid but lets see if i can solve this.

Thanks for all the comments they helped me a lot.

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer, it works for me to.

I have 2 files, which both have the same dojo.js in the script tag (with out any of the data-dojo-conf stuff), one of them works just fine, the other comes up with the error you described in the question.  
I'd be really interested to understand why this is only sometimes an issue when running from the file system.